# For loop for different size of json files

Tags: python, json, for-loop

Let’s say I have multiple json files like:
Example1:

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3",
    "d": "4",
}
```

Example2:

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3"
}
```

Example 3:

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3",
    "d": "4",
    "e": "5"

}
```

etc. I want to iterate these files for example with for loop and print out them into a file based on their elements like:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

or

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
```

My json files are too big and I want to automate this. What would be the easiest way?

Comment: Since you tagged your question `python` `json` and `for-loop`, have you tried writing a short Python script with `import json` and some sort of `for` loop? Please share an attempt and explain where you're stuck exactly. Don't expect StackOverflow to write your code for you.

Comment: Hint: `for k,v in obj.items():`.  Look that up.

Comment: also, for some reason, you used the wrong quotation marks for `d` and `e` in your JSON.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something along these lines.

```
import json
    
filenames = [
    "file1.json",
    "file2.json",
    "file3.json",
]
    
for name in filenames:
    with open(name, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for key in data.keys():
            print(f"{key}: {data[key]}")
```